# Как получить атрибуты ВСЕЙ выборки jquery?

Tags: jquery

Допустим, выборка такая: `$( ".Myclass" )`

Надо получить массив id, у которых данный класс.

Думаю как-то через `.each`, но т.к. в массив js нельзя, как в php, динамически присваивать ($arr[] = ...), то пока не могу найти решение.

Comment: через each http://jsfiddle.net/d3ktprez/

Comment: > т.к. в массив js нельзя как в php динамически присваивать

list.push(value);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var idx = $.map($('.Myclass'), function(o){ return $(o).attr('id') });
```